# python zipfile.BadZipfile: Truncated central directory

Tags: python, zip

I am using zipfile to deal with a large zip file (3.2G). My code is like this.

```
zfile = file('filename.zip')
f = zipfile.ZipFile(zfile, allowZip64=True)`
```

Then there is a Error raised as: BadZipfile("Truncated central directory").

1. If I 'print zipfile.is_zipfile(zfile1)', it is True.
2. I am sure this is a independent zip file, not a multi-disk one.
3. It works well if I use other software to unzip it, such as winrar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python issue with Zipfiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22155594/python-issue-with-zipfiles)

Answer (score 0):

Check the implementation for the zipfile library here:

http://fossies.org/linux/misc/Python-3.3.2.tar.gz:a/Python-3.3.2/Lib/zipfile.py

I'm interested in when the exception you are getting is raised:

```
     sizeCentralDir = struct.calcsize(structCentralDir)
     if len(centdir) != sizeCentralDir:
           raise BadZipFile("Truncated central directory")
```

After checking what is the "central directory structure" in wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29

I think the problem is that your archive size/structure is not supported by the library.