# Python issue with Zipfiles

Tags: python, jar, zip

**DISCLAIMER**: Coding novice

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Evolution/PycharmProjects/MCMODVERSION/stuff/main.py
<open file 'C:\\Users\\Evolution\\Desktop\\mods\\AT_StalkerCreepers_1.6.4.jar', mode 'r' at 0x026F6A18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
True
<zipfile.ZipFile object at 0x02736EB0>
  File "C:/Users/Evolution/PycharmProjects/MCMODVERSION/stuff/main.py", line 80, in <module>
<open file 'C:\\Users\\Evolution\\Desktop\\mods\\BC_AdditionalPipes2.6.0-BC4.2.1.jar', mode 'r' at 0x026F6AC8>
    o = t.getdirList()
True
  File "C:/Users/Evolution/PycharmProjects/MCMODVERSION/stuff/main.py", line 36, in getdirList
    self.getModinfo(os.path.join(p, o[n]), 'name')
  File "C:/Users/Evolution/PycharmProjects/MCMODVERSION/stuff/main.py", line 46, in getModinfo
    y = zipfile.ZipFile(x)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 766, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 832, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile("Truncated central directory")
zipfile.BadZipfile: Truncated central directory

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Code being executed:

```
def getdirList(self):
    p = 'C:\Users\Evolution\Desktop\mods'
    o = [f for f in listdir(p) if isfile(join(p, f))]
    for mod in range(len(o)):
        print o[mod]
        self.getModinfo(os.path.join(p, o[mod]), 'name')


def getModinfo(self,mod,type):
    """ Types:
    modid, name, description, version, mcversion, url
    updateurl, authors, credits, dependencies """
    x = file(mod)
    print x
    print zipfile.is_zipfile(x)
    y = zipfile.ZipFile(x)
    print y
```

Fixed up code:

```
def getdirList(self):
    p = r'C:\Users\Evolution\Desktop\mods'
    o = [f for f in listdir(p) if isfile(join(p, f))]
    for mod in range(len(o)):
        print o[mod]
        self.getModinfo(os.path.join(p, o[mod]), 'name')

def getModinfo(self,mod,type):
    """ Types: modid, name, description, version, mcversion, 
    url, updateurl, authors, credits, dependencies """
    try:
        x = open(mod, 'rb')
        y = zipfile.ZipFile(x)
        z = y.read(self.minfo)
        #print z
        #zz = self.parseIt(z, '%s": ' % type, ',')
        #print zz
    except KeyError:
        print "ERROR: %s has no %s file!" % (x, self.minfo)
        print "%s" % "-" * 50
    x.close()
```

Now I run a check as you can see that says the zip file is, infact, a zip file. This exception is throw for more than half the files. .jar and .zip

Yes I have manually opened them, they are not corrupt or locked or anything. Is there something I can do or perhaps another library I can use for manipulation of achrives in python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zip files are binary files. To handle the binary file correctly you should open the file with binary mode.

Replace following line:

```
x = file(mod)
```

with:

```
x = file(mod, 'rb')
```

---

BTW, escape `\` in the directory path, or use raw string literal. (This is not a direct cause of the problem, but someday escape sequence will trouble you)

```
'C:\\Users\\Evolution\\Desktop\\mods' # escape
```

or

```
r'C:\Users\Evolution\Desktop\mods'    # raw string literal (`r` prefix)
```

Comment: Thank you! I looked at a dozen examples of "zipfile.BadZipfile: Truncated central directory"  before finally coming here. Never once saw the 'rb' thing. I must be blind. Also thanks for the tip about dir paths.

Comment: @PaulDuncan, Use `open` instead of `file`. According to [`file` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file): When opening a file, it’s preferable to use open() instead of invoking this constructor directly.

Comment: @Paul: BTW, it's preferable to use `open()` rather than directly using the `file` function/constructor to open files according to the latter's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file).

Comment: @PaulDuncan, Close resources after you used it. `y.close()` and `x.close()`.

Comment: I've been schooled! I will have to get to making some revisions. Thanks dudes!